# Ruby on Rails how to set new params on HTTParty before redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, request, httparty

I have a POST request with HTTParty, this post validates my params and then redirect me to another page. So there are two requests.

But the second request also require params, how can I pass this params to HTTParty before the redirect?

First request:

```
response = HTTParty.post(URL_TO_SITE, headers: headers, body: params)
# What I need it's something like this
response.before_redirect(params: new_params)
```

I don't know if this is the correct way, so how can I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't the server build the URL to the redirect location correctly? I would argue if you change params on the redirect then you are not following the redirect but just request another URL.

Comment: Yes, it's redirect correctly, I just notice that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable follow redirect (as described here: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/380)
2. Load initial request
3. Save cookies
4. Do manual redirect with the cookies